Sitecore powershell scipt copy langauges and override language fallback
copy/create langauges at sitecore pse is very easy to do.
Add-ItemLanguage $_ -Language $originLanguage -TargetLanguage $destinationLanguages -IfExist $ifExists
but If field has fallback checkbox, it copied as a fallback, that is correct, but I need to skep it for and copy values without fallback, it should be full unique copy.
how to do it with PSE ?
copy just value manually is not working becource it stell make a link to original fallback languages
